# Error in use of the tf.vectorized_map and the tf.linalg.adjoint together

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.vectorized_map(tf.linalg.adjoint,[[[0.92638035,0.86781654,0.07082932,0.05847008,0.8511125,0.36508426,0.93262938,0.50314175,0.42709555,0.70771005],
                                     [0.0939332,0.76758856,0.96512942,0.24077245,0.07860126,0.1635265,0.44031962,0.01234664,0.96572218,0.98906447],
                                     [0.11077884,0.88584282,0.65943618,0.12987475,0.15949519,0.33414308,0.87960809,0.83713104,0.60840816,0.9730074],
                                     [0.23029835,0.6888875,0.80855333,0.31993754,0.45145076,0.63365455,0.87677701,0.72228281,0.91911635,0.95122776],
                                     [0.21333733,0.45232663,0.35471942,0.44432004,0.43770469,0.37246978,0.54925199,0.80986723,0.85000438,0.73820948],
                                     [0.40354433,0.25843004,0.00363146,0.12305595,0.24252965,0.18175492,0.30010179,0.70433849,0.77924173,0.93688071],
                                     [0.78564701,0.53859908,0.14963083,0.95899188,0.92512729,0.29278922,0.54071035,0.71274694,0.34156953,0.80580388],
                                     [0.29272944,0.2288734,0.10608193,0.59221746,0.35921315,0.07014356,0.74207835,0.08194746,0.14855829,0.47673278],
                                     [0.68213703,0.96553305,0.4389587,0.26549066,0.25486691,0.66450013,0.24072084,0.31332454,0.61697049,0.83484757],
                                     [0.86981862,0.96334372,0.86572482,0.91249171,0.25454074,0.32785591,0.97890406,0.97341173,0.08787907,0.09747803]]])
```

TensorFlow version : 2.1.0

When I run the code, there is an error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Can't I use the two APIs together?

---

When I modified the code like this, the code will run normally.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(27).astype(np.float32).reshape(3,3,3)
print(tf.vectorized_map(tf.linalg.adjoint,x))
```

But I found a new probem, the code is as follows.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(18).astype(np.float32).reshape(2,3,3)
print(tf.vectorized_map(tf.linalg.det,x))
```

Part of the error message is below.

```
ValueError: No converter defined for MatrixDeterminant
    name: "loop_body/MatrixDeterminant"
    op: "MatrixDeterminant"
    input: "loop_body/GatherV2"
    attr {
      key: "T"
      value {
        type: DT_FLOAT
      }
    }

    inputs: [WrappedTensor(t=<tf.Tensor 'loop_body/GatherV2/params:0' shape=(2, 3, 3) dtype=float32>, is_stacked=True, is_sparse_stacked=False)]. 
    Either add a converter or set --op_conversion_fallback_to_while_loop=True, which may run slower
```

Is there something wrong with my understanding of the function?

Comment: Can you please try to pass or provide a batch matrix instead of just a list of some arrays?

Comment: It seems that when I replace the array with a batch matrix, the code will run normally. But I find another problem. I will modify the question.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve by this? using the tf.linalg.det produces the determinant from the input matrix so it is the determinant you are passing to vectorize_map. What exactly you wanted to do?

Comment: I am studying how to test the basic API of tensorflow, sorry to trouble you

Answer (score 0):

The first error, `IndexError: list index out of range` is because a `List` has been passed to `tf.vectorized_map(tf.linalg.adjoint` instead of a `Tensor`.

Converting the List to Tensor using the code, `x = tf.constant(x)` will resolve the error.

Please find the working code shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = [[[0.92638035,0.86781654,0.07082932,0.05847008,0.8511125,0.36508426,0.93262938,0.50314175,0.42709555,0.70771005],
                                     [0.0939332,0.76758856,0.96512942,0.24077245,0.07860126,0.1635265,0.44031962,0.01234664,0.96572218,0.98906447],
                                     [0.11077884,0.88584282,0.65943618,0.12987475,0.15949519,0.33414308,0.87960809,0.83713104,0.60840816,0.9730074],
                                     [0.23029835,0.6888875,0.80855333,0.31993754,0.45145076,0.63365455,0.87677701,0.72228281,0.91911635,0.95122776],
                                     [0.21333733,0.45232663,0.35471942,0.44432004,0.43770469,0.37246978,0.54925199,0.80986723,0.85000438,0.73820948],
                                     [0.40354433,0.25843004,0.00363146,0.12305595,0.24252965,0.18175492,0.30010179,0.70433849,0.77924173,0.93688071],
                                     [0.78564701,0.53859908,0.14963083,0.95899188,0.92512729,0.29278922,0.54071035,0.71274694,0.34156953,0.80580388],
                                     [0.29272944,0.2288734,0.10608193,0.59221746,0.35921315,0.07014356,0.74207835,0.08194746,0.14855829,0.47673278],
                                     [0.68213703,0.96553305,0.4389587,0.26549066,0.25486691,0.66450013,0.24072084,0.31332454,0.61697049,0.83484757],
                                     [0.86981862,0.96334372,0.86572482,0.91249171,0.25454074,0.32785591,0.97890406,0.97341173,0.08787907,0.09747803]]]

x = tf.constant(x)
print(type(x))
tf.vectorized_map(tf.linalg.adjoint,x)
```

Regarding the second error, the code `tf.vectorized_map(tf.linalg.det,x)` fails but the code `tf.linalg.det(x)` works fine.

Shown below is the sample working code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(18).astype(np.float32).reshape(2,3,3)
print(tf.linalg.det(x))
```

The reason for the error, `ValueError: No converter defined for MatrixDeterminant` might be because `tf.vectorized_map` doesn't support (or has limited support to) Control Flow statements, as mentioned in [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/vectorized_map).

In case of this statement, `tf.vectorized_map(tf.linalg.det,x)`, before applying `tf.linalg.det`, it might check if the `Matrix`, `x` is a square matrix (as the Determinant can be calculated for only Square Matrices) and that `if loop` might be causing the error.

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!